# c++ how to convert char to int while using `tolower`

Tags: c++

I'm try to compile a simple expression:

```cpp
char_to_int(tolower(row[y]))
```

However I'm getting the following errors when trying to compile it:

```
error: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'int' to 'char' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-int-conversion]
                if (char_to_int(tolower(row[y])) > n
```

The signature of `char_to_int` is:

```
unsigned long char_to_int(char c)
```

and the type of `row[y]` is `char`.

---

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check your code. Unmatched parentheses in `if (char_to_int(tolower(row[y])) > n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*From your error information I assume you are using `std::tolower` from `<cctype>` (or equivalently, `::tolower` from `<ctype.h>`), not `std::tolower` from `<locale>`.*

Why you are getting the error is straightforward from your error information: your `char_to_int` expects a `char`, but `tolower` returns an `int`. This will cause loss of information.

Why does `tolower` return an `int`, not just a `char`? Because it can accept and return EOF, which may fall out of range of any `char`.

The fix can be straightforward: change your `char_to_int` to accept `int`, or do an intermediate step to discard the possible EOF.

Comment: Hmm... I'm dubious, but OK. (Also, incidentally, the `<locale>` version of `std::tolower` has a different signature from the given one anyway.)

Comment: Just edited to make it clear. Hope this time everyone will be happy.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) doesn't actually operate on `char`s: it operates on `int`s! Moreover, there is risk of undefined behaviour: if on your machine `char` is a signed type, then the "negative" characters will correspond to negative integers, which `std::tolower` is not equipped to deal with.

A way to fix this for your use is to manually cast the types before use:

```
char_to_int(static_cast<char>(
   std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(row[y]))));
```

... which unfortunately is a bit of a mess, but that's what you have to do.

Alternatively, you may use the [`locale`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale) version of [`std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower), which is templated and will correctly handle char types. You may use it like so:

```
// std::locale{} is an object representing the default locale
// you may specify a locale precisely if needed; see the above links
char_to_int(std::tolower(row[y], std::locale{}));
```

Answer (score 0):

tolower returns an int. std::tolower is however a template, and will work correctly for  char. In general, if there is a std:: version of any func you are calling, use it! :)